# When instantiating a class, are there rules for not using the same name for the instantiated object as for the class itself?

Tags: python, class, global-variables, instantiation

Suppose I have a class in a module:

```
class c():
    some_var = "abc"

    def f(self):
        print("ok")
```

In a script, I am importing this class and using it as follows:

```
from my_module import c

c = c()
c.f()  # will print "ok"
print(c.some_var)  # will print "abc"
```

I would be doing this because of:

1. readability for the object name; I'm not using the class itself anywhere else, if I have to come up with a different name as the classname itself it would be dubious.
2. avoiding global variables (`some_var`)

Are there any rules for/against it?

Comment: Yes, there are rules against it, namely PEP-8, which recommends upper-case names for classes and lower-case names for variables.

Comment: This is a very bad pattern which lead to a lot of debugging trouble down the line. If you absolutely have to, at least do `from my_module import c as c_class, c = c_class()`

Comment: I have the feeling this is some kind of XY problem. You don't actually need a class here.

Comment: @mkrieger1 . Ok, the X is this: I have a lot of global variables and functions used across scripts. I was reading about this and it was suggested to put variables and constants in a class to avoid having this global Cars. The naming of the variable of the instantiated object is indeed the Y here. 

Comment: So the question is: do you use the class to encapsulate some state and behaviour, or just to bundle some more or less unrelated functions and variables? In the latter case, that's what a module is for. In any case, if you name the class with an uppercase name, then the problem of finding a different name for the instance of it goes away.